# Unbinding events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to unbind this event:

```
$(document).on('change', $('select[name=url]'), function() {}) ;
```

When I unbind this event inside the change event using this, it works:

```
$(this).off();
```

But when I use this, it does not work:

```
$('select[name=url]').off();
```

Secondly, I'd like to unbind the event outside of the change event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove specific delegated event handlers, you must provide a selector argument where the selector string must exactly match the one passed to .on() when the event handler was attached.

This way you dont have to use $(this).off() from inside the onchnage callback. Also, using namespaces for events makes sure you don't unbind any undesired events

Try this.

```js
//here the namespace name is set to 'selection'
$(document).on('change.selection', 'select[name=url]', function() {
  alert("Change event triggered");
})

$("button").click(function() {
  $(document).off('change.selection', 'select[name=url]')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="url">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button>Unbind</button>
```

Comment: You might want to suggest OP to use namespaces, that is a really handy feature of jQuery, too ;)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! Works just like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse the event `on('change')` is bindded to the document not to the element `('select[name=url]')`.

If you want to set the event change for every element select, the best option is to set a common class and bind the change event to the class.

If you do that, you can unbind the event inside and outside to the change event